# Mounting a host directory to a docker container from yaml/compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have part of my current config like this

```
mymicroservice:
  image: service_img
  networks: myoverlay
  volumes:
    - /Users/abcdUser/mountme:/opt/company/
```

This does the job as my machine's directory gets mounted to `/opt/company` when I deploy the docker swarm service stack.

However, I want to specify the source directory under a separate `volumes:` and then specify that name over there. I think this is possible but I am not able to find the syntax.

So I want something along the following lines but not able to do so:

```
mymicroservice:
  image: service_img
  networks: myoverlay
  volumes:
    - myownvolume:/opt/company/


volumes:
 - myownvolume: /Users/abcdUser/mountme
```

I want to clarify that `myownvolume` here is just pointing to the directory `/Users/abcdUser/mountme` and I am not intending to create a docker volume. Or there is any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do so but not with the standard setup. The default volume driver doesn't allow the format you are looking for. You need to use docker plugins which requires external installation. Consider the below yaml

```
version: '2'

services:
  one:
    image: alpine
    working_dir: /one/
    command: sleep 600
    volumes:
      - data:/one/

  two:
    image: alpine
    working_dir: /two/
    command: sleep 600
    volumes:
      - data:/two/

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data
```

Above would work when you have the local-persist plugin installed. https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist

You can find about other plugins available on

https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#volume-plugins

Also if repetition of volumes entries is an issues for you then you can use anchors in YAML

```
version: '3'

services:
  alpines:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 200
    volumes: &common_volumes
      - ./data:/data
      - ./config:/config
  alpine2:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 200
    volumes: *common_volumes

$ docker-compose config
services:
  alpine2:
    command: sleep 200
    image: alpine
    volumes:
    - /home/vagrant/so/volumes2/data:/data:rw
    - /home/vagrant/so/volumes2/config:/config:rw
  alpines:
    command: sleep 200
    image: alpine
    volumes:
    - /home/vagrant/so/volumes2/data:/data:rw
    - /home/vagrant/so/volumes2/config:/config:rw
version: '3.0'
```

Comment: this is very helpful. Long story short, if I want to avoid any plugins, what I have done is the only route without installing any 3rd party plugins?

Comment: Yes, then you need to use what you have used

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You either have to use the bind mount syntax or the volume syntax. Volumes at the compose config top level won't allow you to mix both. See [how to define a general mount point in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899836/how-to-define-a-general-mount-point-in-docker-compose) for a similar question.