# Mounted host volume is not writable from host in Azure Pipelines

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, ubuntu, azure-pipelines

I'm mounting a volume from host to container which will not be present at the time of running the docker container.

```yaml
  volumes:
    - "../foo:/app/foo"
```

The `foo` folder will be created by the docker. The container will create additional folders and files inside `foo`. Similarly one more app inside the host will create additional folders and files inside `foo`. My expectation is that all the content should be placed inside the `foo` folder from the container app and the host app.

This works fine in the Mac, but running the same in Azure Pipelines fails to create additional files and folders from the host.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir './foo'
      at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:921:3)
```

I have tried adding `z` at the end of volume mount but it didn't worked - `../foo:/app/foo:Z`. I tried to run `chmod`, but the operation is not permitted.

Azure Pipeline:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to make a folder on a pipleine:

```html
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'mkdir .foo' 
    workingDirectory: System.DefaultWorkingDirectory
```

so that would essentially make a .foo folder in System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/.foo

Now if you then wanted to go into that folder you can do:

```html
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd '($System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.foo'
      dir
```

Or you could do to just see the full path to ref in your code:

```html
- task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo '($System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.foo'
```

Then once the file has been made you can mount it using docker an answer here may help with that:

[Mounting a host directory to a docker container from yaml/compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062593/mounting-a-host-directory-to-a-docker-container-from-yaml-compose-file)

Essentially you have to switch your steps around.

Comment: Creating the folder before running `docker compose up` did the trick.

Comment: Nice thought it might. Well done